# Landsat 8 to the temperature map (in ArcGIS 10.0 -10.2.2 or ENVI 5.0)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, envi, landsat-8

I need to create a temperature map from Landsat 8. I found  an algorithm that explains how to do it in ArcGIS:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/06/deriving-temperature-from-landsat-8-thermal-bands-tirs/

Unfortunately I can’t use this method, because the “local function” (that is used in Step 3  - “To calculate the natural log, you need to use local function”) is blocked in my version of ArcGIS. The program gives: NOT LICENSED "This raster function requires a license"
It’s strange, because now I use the trial version of ArcGIS 10.2.2 (that gives all possibilities for 2 months), maybe I can find this function somewhere?

Also I tried to realize this algorithm on the permanent version of ArcGIS 10.0 But here I can’t find the Raster Function Template Editor" (from Step 1 – B) (I don’t have any “Commands” in Customize >>Raster).
So, two problems in the both versions of ArcGIS  that I can’t solve.

But as I understood, this method explains how to create a Function chain which can be used for any Landsat 8 for preparing a temperature map.  Maybe some special script for ArcGIS for  this purpose  has been developed?

Or maybe you can advise how I can create a temperature map from Landsat 8 in ArcGIS (by dint of this method or other).
Also I have ENVI 5.0,  so I’ll  be glad advises for method by dint of ENVI as well.

Comment: With ArcGIS for Desktop I think you need Spatial Analyst installed, licensed and turned on - under Customize | Extensions make sure that is available and checked on.

Comment: Thank you! I’ve found this option and realized the algorithm described on link above for conversion Landsat-8 to a surface temperature map.

Comment: But now I have another question about this method. I’ve implemented all steps very precisely (converted to the Celsius degrees, not to Fahrenheit degrees), but the final raster has values of pixels like a  28122, 30472. They look like Celsius degree multiplied by 1000). However, there are no words about it in the algorithm. 
So, I don’t know – I obtained the correct result of the surface temperature (and need so divide them on 1000), or this result is incorrect?

Comment: It sounds like my comment resolved your first question so I have moved it to become an answer.  So that the focussed Q&A format that we use here is followed, I recommend that you research/ask any follow on questions separately.  You can always copy/cut & paste those unanswered portions from your question/comments here into a new question.

Answer (score 0):

With ArcGIS for Desktop I think you need Spatial Analyst installed, licensed and turned on in order to use any raster functions that are saying that they are "NOT LICENSED".

I suspect that the step skipped from the above is that you may not have gone to Customize | Extensions make sure that is available and checked on.

Comment: In envi 5 you search in the toolbox "radiometric calibration ", then select thermal bands,  in calibration type choose "brightness temperature ". If you need more accuracy you will need atmospherical correction and emissivity